# WSO2 EI 6.3.0 unable to connect with IBM Websphere MQ v8 using JMS

Tags: wso2, jms, websphere, ibm-mq, wso2-esb

I am trying to connect WSO2 Enterprise Integrator with IBM Websphere MQ v 8.0.0.5 by JMS Transport. The purpose is to be able to receive/publish messages on Queues that are made in IBM Websphere MQ via WSO2 Enterprise Integrator using JMS Protocol.

**Link:**

I followed this [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Configure+with+IBM+WebSphere+MQ#ConfigurewithIBMWebSphereMQ-generate) provided by WSO2 official documentation. I followed all the steps exactly but when I deploy the JMS Listener Proxy, it becomes a **faulty** service and It shows me the following error on the console:

**Error Stack Trace:**

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:412)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7913)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:299)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:236)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6024)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:136)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:209)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:786)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener.checkJMSConnection(JMSListener.java:155)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener.startEndpoint(JMSListener.java:99)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener.startEndpoint(JMSListener.java:54)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListenerEx.startListeningForService(AbstractTransportListenerEx.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.internalStartListeningForService(AbstractTransportListener.java:213)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener$2.serviceAdded(AbstractTransportListener.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.tracker.AxisServiceTracker.serviceAdded(AxisServiceTracker.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.tracker.AxisServiceTracker$1.serviceUpdate(AxisServiceTracker.java:98)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.notifyObservers(AxisConfiguration.java:666)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.addServiceGroup(AxisConfiguration.java:420)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.addService(AxisConfiguration.java:350)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService.buildAxisService(ProxyService.java:750)
    at org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin.addProxyService(ProxyServiceAdmin.java:273)
    at org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin.addProxy(ProxyServiceAdmin.java:710)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

**Proxy Service Code as mentioned in documentation:**

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="MyJMSProxy"
       transports="jms"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <drop/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">LocalQueue1</parameter>
</proxy>
```

**Axis2 File Configuration:**
Following are axis2 configurations for transport receiver and transport listener.

**Transport Receiver:**

```
    <transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
  <parameter name="default" locked="false">
    <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:/C:/jndidirectory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">MyQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false">omerk</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false">password</parameter>
  </parameter>
 
 
  <parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory1" locked="false">
    <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:/C:/jndidirectory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">MyQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false">omerk</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false">password</parameter>
  </parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

**Transport Listener:**

```
<transportSender name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender">
  <parameter name="default" locked="false">
    <parameter name="vender.class.loader.enabled">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:/C:/jndidirectory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">MyQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false">omerk</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false">password</parameter>
  </parameter>
 
  <parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory1" locked="false">
    <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:/C:/jndidirectory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">MyQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false">omerk</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false">password</parameter>
  </parameter>
</transportSender>
```

**Research So far:**

I tried googling it and apparently it is showing that It is not able to figure out the Queue Manager Name. But I am unable to figure out where to add this information and how? I tried adding it on the JMS Proxy Service Level Parameters but it didn't work. So any insight would be helpful.

Comment: The important file is your axis2.xml file. Edit your question and add it.

Comment: @Roger I have updated the question with axis2 configuration.

Comment: Do you have a ".bindings" file located where "java.naming.provider.url" points to?  And shouldn't that value be "file:/C:/jndidirectory"? What did you put in the MQ JNDI file?  Show your commands.  Also, having a blank in your UserName is probably wrong.

Comment: @Roger yes, I have the bindings file at the given location. I have updated the file location as well. I wrote it because it is mentioned in the wso2 documentation. But it is also not working. User name is also updated but it didn't solve the problem either. Where can I find MQ JNDI file.

Comment: The ".bindings" is the MQ JNDI file.  You need to show the commands you used to create the QCF and Q entries in the MQ JNDI file.

Comment: I created the .bindings file via Webshpere MQ. Not by commands. You can refer to the section: Generate .bindings file in the above documentation.

Comment: I presume you mean MQ Explorer.  Until you show me the commands or issue DIS QCF(*) and DIS Q(*) via JMSAdmin.bat (or JMSAdmin.sh) and update the question then there is nothing I can do.

Answer (score 0):

**TroubleShooting**

For Troubleshooting, when I checked the Error logs of IBM Websphere MQ. IT was giving the following error:

```
AMQ5534: User ID 'omerk' authentication failed

EXPLANATION:
The user ID and password supplied by the 'carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap' program
could not be authenticated.
```

**Solution:**

For my solution the authentication was not a requirement. So I basically disabled the authentication of my queue manager by running the following commands.

```
ALTER AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS) AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) CHCKCLNT(NONE)

REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```

IT worked for me and solved my problem.